# Как преобразовать список строк в список списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

На входе имеется список:

```
['Иванов Сергей 14 56\n', 'Сергеев Петр 23 74\n']
```

Нужно получить

```
[[Иванов, Сергей, 14, 56], [Сергеев, Петр, 23, 74]]
```

Пробовала так:

```
lines = ['Иванов Сергей 14 56\n', 'Сергеев Петр 23 74\n']
myList = []
for line in lines:
    myList[line] = lines[line].split(' ')
```

Получаю ошибку:

> ```
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> ```

Похоже, 
вообще не то делаю ... буду благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**вариант 1:**

```
In [183]: [x.split() for x in lines]
Out[183]: [['Иванов', 'Сергей', '14', '56'], ['Сергеев', 'Петр', '23', '74']]
```

**вариант 2:**

```
In [184]: list(map(str.split, lines))
Out[184]: [['Иванов', 'Сергей', '14', '56'], ['Сергеев', 'Петр', '23', '74']]
```

**ваш вариант (слегка исправленный):**

```
In [190]: myList = []
     ...: for line in lines:
     ...:     myList.append(line.split())
     ...: print(myList)
     ...:
[['Иванов', 'Сергей', '14', '56'], ['Сергеев', 'Петр', '23', '74']]
```

**причина возникновения** `"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"`:

итерируя по списку - `for line in lines` переменной `line` будет последовательно присвоено значение каждой строки из списка - т.е. тип переменной `line` - строка:

```
In [191]: for line in lines:
     ...:     print(line, type(line))
     ...:
     ...:
Иванов Сергей 14 56
 <class 'str'>
Сергеев Петр 23 74
 <class 'str'>
```

индексирование в списках в Python по строке не предусмотрено, поэтому следующие конструкции будут вызывать данную ошибку:

```
myList[line]
lines[line]
```

---

```
In [192]: line = lines[0]

In [193]: myList[line]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-582d92ae9dea> in <module>()
----> 1 myList[line]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Оооо, как же это прекрасно! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Lazarevna, всегда рад помочь :)